# NextJs deploy on vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I get the following errors while deploying my nextjs app on vercel. However my app runs all right with no errors in localhost but while deploying it is giving me the errors  attached in the images[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozwE.png)

[This is my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG4yH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW7J4.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have error on [slug].js file
befor deploy on vercel run this commands and check the app run on your compouter or not

```
yarn run build

yarn start
```

Comment: im getting same error when i run 'yarn run build'

Answer (score 0):

fix this issue in pizza/[slug] file :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

and deploy it again

Comment: image is correct i checked all